# Deriving algorithm for grouping the nearest items

Tags: geometry, discrete-mathematics, algorithms

Please help me arriving at an algorithm for the below scenario.

**Scenario:**

A database has coins, ID and value. There are 1500 coins. Each coin is having a unique ID which start from 1 till 1500. The value will change based on the market.

Lets us say I have around 30 coins which are picked out of the 1500 coins. All are scattered widely in the 1500 available coins.

**Problem**

In every call to the database it returns only 100 coins from the starting position we provide. This result will have only some of the 30 coins that we have

**Goal**

I have to fetch all the 30 coins with minimum number of calls to the database.

Example.. Please see the coin name and the ID. In the below example I am making 9 calls to get the details of all the coins. Surely there will be a better way to reduce the number of calls by following a algorithm which can be used commonly in all cases.

[image]

Comment: Nope: the greedy algorithm that you used for the example set, always yields the smallest number of calls/spans.

Comment: Will it give me the starting ID for every call ?

Comment: Yes. Like I answered: sort the IDs, then do a call with starting ID the smallest not yet covered ID, until you have covered all IDs.

Comment: yes IDs are already in sorted order..

Answer (score 1):

Let's recap:

- There is a set of $n$ unique nonnegative integers $k_i$, $i = 1 \dots n$.
- Each call spans a fixed range $[a,\; a+L-1]$, inclusive

  (In OP's case, $L=100$.)
- The task is to find the minimum number of spans to cover all $k_i$

This is the one-dimensional ($d=1$) [geometric set cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_set_cover_problem), for which a simple greedy algorithm will find the solution (but only in the one-dimensional case) in polynomial time.

(The time complexity is typically $O(n^2)$ or $O(n \log n)$, depending on your sort algorithm. If there exists an integer $K$ such that $0 \le k_i \le K$ for all $n$, then a radix sort can do this in $O(n)$ time complexity. However, for small $n$ like $n = 30$, any sort algorithm, even bubble sort, will perform acceptably in practice; use the one your programming language provides.)

The [greedy algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm) is easiest to implement as follows:

1. Sort $k_i$ in ascending order, so that $k_i \lt k_{i+1}$ for $i = 1 \dots n-1$.
2. Each span will be $[k_i ,\, k_i + L - 1]$, inclusive, for the smallest $i$ not yet covered by a span.

In pseudocode:

```
Function Spans(Input  ID[], 
               Input  IDs,
               Input  width,
               Output span[]):

    Sort ID in ascending order

    Let  id_min_index = 1
    Let  id_min = ID[id_min_index]
    Let  id_max = ID[IDs]
    Let  spans = 1

    # Loop over all spans except the last one.
    While (id_max - id_min > width):

        # Span covers 'width' integers
        span[spans].start = id_min
        span[spans].end = id_min + width - 1
        spans = spans + 1

        # Skip the already covered IDs.
        id_min = id_min + width
        While (ID[id_min_index] < id_min):
            id_min_index = id_min_index + 1
        End While
        id_min = ID[id_min_index]

    End While

    # Final span.
    span[spans].start = id_min
    span[spans].end = id_min + width - 1

    Return spans
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for your time...       I know java.. Could you please let me know what program language is this ?
Where I would get the starting point for each calls ?
Could you please point me an example / link which explains clear ? I am still feeling it hard to understand

Comment: @iappmaker: It is just [pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode), intended to be human-readable, rather than any specific programming language.  It really just picks the smallest ID left, removes all IDs between that one and that one + 99, and does the call starting at that one ID. Repeat, until you have no IDs left. If you do not know how to implement that, it is time to go back to Java tutorials, and work your way up until you learn how.

Answer (score 0):

If the set of possible IDs is reasonably small then the following approach could allow all 30 coins to be retrieved with one database call.

I am assuming that a database call is "Give me entries $X$" where $X$ is a set of *pointers* (or whatever indexing scheme is used by the database). From your problem description, $X$ is allowed to have at most 100 entries at a time.

I also assume that you know the IDs of your 30 coins.

*Proposed solution*:

- Let $n$ be the number of possible IDs. Let $\mathcal{L}$ be a list of size $n$ such that $\mathcal{L}(i)$ is points to the coin with ID $i$.  So for example $\mathcal{L}(1160934)$ points to the coin with ID "1160934".  In your situation, you will have $n \geq 1500$ and most likely $n \gg 1500$.
- When you want to get your 30 coins, you look up $\mathcal{L}(i)$ for each ID $i$ of those coins. This will construct a set of pointers $X$.
- Call the database with $X$.  As 30 < 100, this can be done in one call.

Basically, this solution trades 'calls to database' for storage (a variant on having smaller runtime complexity at the expense of larger storage complexity).

Comment: I can request the database only with the Starting position of ID and ending position of ID. It will give the coins with the ID in the specified range of Starting and ending position. Some coin may be in first 100 and some may be in 50 to 150.. and some may be in 320 to 420..